# Given the following structure, how do I translate the these statements into formulas in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The following is a problem from our book in predicate logic.

"Work over the arity type: 'one binary relation, one constant symbol, one binary operation' and then consider the structure
$$
Q := \ <\mathbb{Q};\leq;1,+>
$$
(a) Give a formula that represents the statement: "$x_0$ is equal to 1/2" in $Q$.

(b) Give a formula that represents the statement: "$x_0 \leq 0$" in $Q$.

(c) Give a formula that represents the statement: "there does not exist any $x_1$ that is strictly greater than $x_0$" in $Q$."

I have an idea as to how to construct the formula in the first question: if one has "$x_0 \leq 1/2$" and "$1/2 \leq x_0$", one can deduce $x_0 = 1/2$. My initial attempt looked something like this:
$$
P_1\big(x_0, f_1/(f_2(f_1,f_1))\big) \wedge P_1\big(f_1/(f_2(f_1,f_1)), x_0\big)
$$
where $P_1$ represents the relation symbol $\leq$; $f_1$ represents the constant symbol 1 and $f_2$ the binary operation $+$. I doubt this is correct, since I've used the operator "/", which is not part of my structure. As for the rest, I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: "x0 is equal to 1/2" will be $x_0+x_0=1$

Comment: $0$ is the unique number $x_0$ such that $1+x_0=1$

Comment: Thank you for the comment @MauroALLEGRANZA ! I see now where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the answer to this problem has to use the formula $2x = 1$ to define the number 1/2. You don't have the function symbol $/$ in your structure. So your attempt cannot succeed, because you are writing your formula:

$$P_1\big(x_0, f_1/(f_2(f_1,f_1))\big) \wedge P_1\big(f_1/(f_2(f_1,f_1)), x_0\big)$$

with a $/$ symbol. You don't have $/$ defined in the structure, not to say in the language. Note also (I am guessing this is your nomenclature) that the language itself has only the symbols:

$$f_1, f_2, P_1, =, \land, \neg, \exists $$

Suppose you had $/$ in your structure and a symbol $f_3$ in the language corresponding to it, and suppose it is well defined everywhere but not in 0 for the denominator, you could just write the formula that says $x_0 = 1/2$:

$$ x_0 = f_3(f_1,f_2(f_1,f_1))$$

Your answer should fit also, with this extra $f_3$ in the place of $/$.

But you don't have this symbol. So you have to do this trick:

$$f_2(x_0 ,x_0) = f_1$$

to represent the statement.

The same goes for the others ones. As for the third one, note that you don't have the symbol $<$ in  your structure, but you can create it by this trick:

$$(x_0 \leq x1) \land  \neg (x_0 = x_1)$$

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! Really greatful that you took the time to explain the details in how to work around the problem of certain symbols not being included in the structure.

Comment: You are welcome.